# React Transition Group And Animations

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup, react-transition-group

The problem is I have a form whit three states: default, error and success. Depending on the state, a specific component is rendered into the dom. 
I need to add a fade in out animation when this component enters or leave.

I've tried whith custom CSS, GSAP ( but don't want to install more packages to my project ) and now trying with react-transition-group.

To keep is simple I've created the "error" component as follow:

```
export default class NewsletterFormError extends React.Component {
   componentWillMount() {
   }
   componentDidMount() {
   }
   render() {
      return (
        <div className="NewsletterFormError">
          I'm an error message
        <style jsx>{`
          .NewsletterFormError {
            font-size: 50px;
          }  
        `}</style>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And on the index page I have:

```
    { this.state.formError &&
        <CSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName="test"
        transitionAppear={true}
        transitionAppearTimeout={200}            
        transitionEnter={true}
        transitionEnterTimeout={2000}
        transitionLeave={true}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={2000}>
          <NewsletterFormError />
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
      }
```

For some reson, when `this.state.formError` is `true`, the component renders and the fade in is done, but when the state chages to `false`, the fade out is not working.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, pure React CSS Transition groups can't trigger an animation when a component is unmounted. See [this github issue](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/issues/30) for more details. [This repo with a comparison of animation methods in react](https://github.com/aholachek/react-animation-comparison) may be helpful, they recommend using React CSS Transition groups in conjunction with GSAP or Anime.js